# Firefox cannot open cross domain WebSocket connection

Tags: firefox, websocket, cross-domain

Firefox 29.0.1 (the latest) cannot open a wss:// connection to another domain.

Chrome and IE work without problem, but Firefox fails and shows this message on the console:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://x.mobile.whatever.com/.
```

The page is served from `http://localhost` and accessed locally. I have checked  `about:config` and WebSockets are enabled.

Any idea about which is the cause or how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Check if your antivirus blocks Firefox

Comment: Do you send correct CORS headers?

Comment: Websocket do not use CORS